# migrate model slug field to unique for existing database

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

In old database slug field was not unique, so duplicates are created. Now i want to migrate slug field unique=True.

```
slug = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

$ python manage.py migrate

django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry 'some-x-slug' for key 'some_model_slug_6c7ae6ae040a5e98_uniq'")
```

is it possible when migrating if django detects duplicate slug, i want to add `object_id` at the end of that `slug` field, to make that slug unique.

is there any easy solution for above problem

Comment: Which version of django/south are you using?

Comment: @tutuDajuju using Django 1.8,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Updating your migration with the following `RunPython` operation should probably suffice. Follow [this Django guide on writing migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/writing-migrations/#migrations-that-add-unique-fields) for reasoning and more examples.

#### your_new_migration.py

```
def update_slugs(apps, schema_editor):
    SomeModel = apps.get_model("some_app", "SomeModel")

    for instance in SomeModel.objects.all():
        instance.slug = '%s-%s' % (instance.slug, instance.object_id)
        instance.save()


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        # ... your existing dependencies
    ]

    operations = [
        # add this operation ...
        migrations.RunPython(update_slugs, reverse_code=migrations.RunPython.noop),

        # ... before your original migration, such as:
        # migrations.AlterField(
        #     model_name='somemodel',
        #     name='slug',
        #     field=models.CharField(unique=True),
        # ),
    ]
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly. to only update duplicate slugs in above code,  dupe_slug = SomeModel.objects.values('slug').annotate(Count('slug')).order_by().filter(slug__count__gt=1)
dup_objects = SomeModel.objects.filter(slug__in=[item['slug'] for item in dupe_slug]) instead of changing all objects slug change slug of dup_objects.